# Using own app as a full version (In-App-Purchase)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I know, I can't buy my own app, but actually, I would like to use my own app as a full version app without having to touch my code. I'm using an In-App-Purchase for this.

Is there some way to achieve that?

I know, for paid apps I can return a static response for my developer account, but I can't find anything similar for one time in-app-purchases...